# Construct an automata for this language

Tags: computer-science, automata, finite-automata

Let $\mathcal{L}_1$ be the language over alphabet $\{0,1\}^*$. Define language $\mathcal{L}_2$, call even-$\mathcal{L}_1$, as:

$$\mathcal{L}_2 = \{ w_2 w_4 \ldots w_{k} ~:~ w_1 w_2 w_3 w_4 \ldots w_{k-1} w_{k} \in \mathcal{L}_1, ~ \text{k even} \}$$

I would like to construct a DFA or NFA for $\mathcal{L}_2$, but I am having trouble visualizing this computation.

One idea for constructing an automata for $\mathcal{L}_2$ is to suppose that $\mathcal{L_1}$ is composed of two languages:

$$\mathcal{L}_2 = \{ w_2 w_4 \ldots w_{k} ~:~ w_1 w_2 w_3 w_4 \ldots w_{k-1} w_{k} \in \mathcal{L}_1, ~ \text{k even} \}\\
\mathcal{L}_3 = \{ w_1 w_3 \ldots w_{k-1} ~:~ w_1 w_2 w_3 w_4 \ldots w_{k-1} w_{k} \in \mathcal{L}_1, ~ \text{k-1 odd} \}.$$

So that $$\mathcal{L}_1 = \mathcal{L}_2 ~\text{`interleave`}~ \mathcal{L}_3.$$
But then I need to define interleave in terms the automata it operates over, and prove that interleave takes two regular languages and construct another regular language, and since $\mathcal{L}_1$ is regular by assumption, then $\mathcal{L}_2$ and $\mathcal{L}_3$ must both be regular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Suppose you have an automata for $\mathcal L_1$. Duplicate its set of states and send the letters between them in both directions.

Comment: What does it mean when you say "send the letters between them in both directions"?

Comment: So, say $\mathcal L_1$ has a state called $S$ and it gets to state $T$ upon letter $x$. Then, $\mathcal L_2$ will have states $S_1, S_2$ and $T_1,T_2$ and letter $x$ turns $S_1$ to state $T_2$ and $S_2$ to $T_1$.